# Python MCP23017 16 ch. I2C input losing a bit

Tags: python, i2c

I bought a MCP23017 and doing some small test with it. I've made a simple Python script to make read_out of pin state.
Can anyone explain to me, why I'm losing a bit when GPIO_A7 is triggered?
I've got 8 bit readout and all input changers state from 1 to 0 except GPIO_A7
so it looks like this:

GPIO_A0 = 11111110, GPIO_A1 = 11111101
But when hitting GPIO_A7 = 1111111

So I've only get 7 bit and not 8?

Hope for some help. :-)

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    #
    # Input / output MCP23017

    import smbus
    import sys
    import time

     bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
     once = False

     def start_up(once):
         if once != True:
         bus.write_byte_data(0x22, 0x00, 0xFF) # set input bank a
         time.sleep(0.1)
         bus.write_byte_data(0x22, 0x01, 0xFF) # set input bank b
         time.sleep(0.1)
         bus.write_byte_data(0x22, 0x0C, 0xFF) # set pull-up resistor
         time.sleep(0.1)
         bus.write_byte_data(0x22, 0x0D, 0xFF) # set pull-up resister
         time.sleep(0.1)
         once = True
    return once

    def read_data(bank):
        if bank == 0:
            state = bus.read_byte_data(0x22, 0x12)
            time.sleep(0.5)
         return state

    def main():
        start_up(once)
            while True:
            state = read_data(0)
        print bin(state)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.
It's not a bug. Is it the conversion between Hex and Binary.
I think is the way that Python do the conversion, that removing the first 0 and just show 1111111.

Comment: However this is still a known bug of the MCP23017.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked too carefully at your question but it seems to be related to a feature or bug or whatever you choose to call it of some MCP23017.

The answer seems to be don't use A7 or B7 as inputs.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=637787